# UIButton hidden behind UIToolbar

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitoolbar

**Context**

I've got a UIButton that I'm adding, method is below:

```
[self.view addSubview:[self returnCustomSubmitButton]];
```

I don't add the toolbar as a subview, I set the ViewControllers navigationController property toolBarHidden to NO. - `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];` at viewWill apear

**Extra Detail**

The reason I'm doing this is because I want to create something like the toolbar (NOTE: This is a UITabBar, but I'm looking for the same shape) below - so I'm adding a toolbar and then adding a UIButton to the viewControllers view and using the toolbars coordinates to position the UIButton

[image: This is the form I want to create]

I've tried to follow along to this (NOTE: Again this is for a UITabBar), but struggling: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

**Problem**

**The UIButton is hidden behing the UIToolbar (I want it to sit on top of the toolbar).**

**Questions**

- How do I solve this?
- Would it be a better approach to convert a UIButton to a UIBarButtItem? And add a UIButton to a viewController's toolbarItems array?
- How would I do this?

**Update**

After lots of attempts at fixing this, is this something to do with the fact I'm using UINavigationController and the fact that I'm adding a UIButton to the "Custom Content" area and the nav toolbar sits on top of that whatever I do. See below:

[image]

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion... this (screenshot + link) is a `UITabBar`

Comment: Good point - I'll include in question.

Comment: Regarding your last update (custom content), I offer an explanation for this in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think that the best solution is to create your `UIToolbar` programmatically and then create and add any custom `UIBarButtonItem`s, here is a possible solution to your problem:

(**Note**: Apple says that [you must not try to modify `UINavigationController`'s default toolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so if you're planning to do so try the above suggestion)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Show the default toolbar
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    // Create a UIButton
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];

    // Add your targets/actions
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Position the button
    // I am sure that there must be
    // a million better ways to do this
    // (it's here just to illustrate the point)
    button.center = self.navigationController.toolbar.center;
    CGRect frame = button.frame;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) - button.frame.size.height;
    button.frame = frame;

    // Here is the tricky part. Toolbar is not part
    // of your controller's view hierarchy, it belongs
    // to the navigation controller. So add the button there 
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: It's still sitting behind. Continue to dig.

Comment: @drc I'm positive that this works, I have tested the code before posting the answer.

Comment: I'll continue to try to get it to work. Thanks for your help so far and your time, appreciate it.

Comment: can you clarify your comment around Apple guideline on not modifying the "default toolbar", I am planning on having a custom toolbar in the app, and I was creating a UIToolBar and adding it a subview of the UIViewController, however I reverted back to using navigationController setToolBarHidden NO as I was struggling to keep the toolbar @ the right Y pos. The app also hides and shows a nav bar in a certain context and when trying to support 4inch screen height it got too complex to keep setting the "custom" toolbar's frame.

Comment: Are you saying that creating a UIToolbar and adding it as a subview of the ViewControllers view is a custom toolbar created programmatically. And that setting the ViewControllers property - toolBarHidden to NO means you are using the "default" toolbar.

Comment: Yes exactly. I think that the best solution would be to create one programmatically and add it to navigation controller's view hierarchy to maintain persistence.

Comment: Also note that when you're using the default one, the right way to add items to it is to call `setToolbarItems:` on each of your controllers, passing the respective items.

Comment: I was using that but it wasn't working. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219160/subclassing-uitoolbar-and-overriding-drawrect-uibarbuttonitems-not-displaying

Comment: ugg. I had the toolbar sit to visible after adding the custom button. I swapped the order and this now fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of this code.

```
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, let me follow up with more detail tomorrow.

Comment: I don't add the toolbar as a subview, I set the ViewControllers navigationController property toolBatHidden to NO. - [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO]; at viewWill apear

Answer (score 0):

use this codes

```
[self.view insertSubview:[self returnCustomSubmitButton] aboveSubview:toolbar];
```

then your button will be above the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks this doesn't seem to work either, let me check more in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:your buttons, nil]
[toolbar setItems:items];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

this may help you

Comment: The button is a UIButton not a UIBarButtonItem.